# Zend Oracle default date format

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework

In my project I'm using Zend framework with Oracle. When I'm trying to get info in a way like this:

```
$comments = $this->commentModel->fetchAll($where, array('PERSON_COMMENT_ID ASC'));

$list = array();
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $list[] = array(
      'text' => "{$comment['TEXT']}",
      'date' => $comment['CREATION_DATE'],
      'comment_id' => "{$comment['PERSON_COMMENT_ID']}",
      'person_id' => "{$person_id}"
    );
}
```

Oracle returns me date in format `dd.MM.YY`.

How can I get dates in format `dd.MM.YYYY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to change what columns you select (change `CREATION_DATE` to `TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'dd.MM.YYYY')`) you will need to prepare a SELECT object, specify the desired columns and then pass it to `fetchAll` in place of the `$where` argument.

So

```
$select = $this->commentModel->select()
    ->columns(array(..., new Zend_Db_Expr("TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'dd.MM.YYYY')")))
    ->where(...);

$comments = $this->commentModel->fetchAll($select, array('PERSON_COMMENT_ID ASC'));
```

Hope that helps. Also, I haven't tested this, so no guarantee it will parse and/or run correctly ;)

Edit:

Since you iterate over each row anyway, you could just `date($format, strtotime($comment['CREATION_DATE']));` the whole thing.